# Send email without server using google script: unable to open file error

Tags: javascript, html, email, google-apps-script, forms

I want to send an email to a location **target@example.com** using google script 
. I am following this - https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server
to setup the whole functionality in my website.

There is an html form in my website and I want to send email whenever someone clicks on the submit button on my site

here is the html of the form -

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  <h4>Fill out the form below and a representative will
contact you shortly.</h4>
  <form id="gform" method="POST" action="https://script.google.com/macros/u/1/s/AKfycbwYbJ5WvIRmizYMr8MMtNVdIodpdYcJHz4DuO97Oxnuw4lnu3k/exec">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Your Name (required)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Your Email (required)</label>
    <input type="Email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Message</label>
   <textarea class="message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Here is the script.gs file -

```js
/******************************************************************************
 * This tutorial is based on the work of Martin Hawksey twitter.com/mhawksey  *
 * But has been simplified and cleaned up to make it more beginner friendly   *
 * All credit still goes to Martin and any issues/complaints/questions to me. *
 ******************************************************************************/

var TO_ADDRESS = "target@example.com"; // where to send form data

function doPost(e) {

  try {
    Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger
    MailApp.sendEmail(TO_ADDRESS, "Contact Form Submitted",
                      JSON.stringify(e.parameters));
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}
```

When I click on submit button after filling in the form I get this -

[image]

I get the same screen when I click on Test web app on your latest code.

**What I've found out -**

There is something I need to add to my html tags inside form as "name" attribute but its not very clear what to add.

Where am I going wrong in setting up this feature ?

Comment: There can be many problem. Have you set the trigger in your gs script console? Secontly, I don't think you can post using action tag in form. You have to look for when button is clicked on submit, then make an ajax request to the url (https://script.google.com/macros/u/1/s/AKfycbwYbJ5WvIRmizYMr8MMtNVdIodpdYcJHz4DuO97Oxnuw4lnu3k/exec), which always doesn't seem to work. did you deploy correctly? Would require more info

Comment: Leave the working of button the url itself is not working when I open it as "Test web app for your latest code" link after deploying.

Comment: I've done exactly like what was there in the tutorial from points 1 to 7. Except these instructions I've not added anything from my side.

Comment: If i remove /u/1 then url becomes https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwYbJ5WvIRmizYMr8MMtNVdIodpdYcJHz4DuO97Oxnuw4lnu3k/exec and runs. But gives the error: Script function not found: doGet . Do you have a doGet function in your script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think I have figured out your problem.

There seems to be two problem:

- **You seemed to be logged in with two gmail account:** That is why /u/1 got appended to script address (we don't need it, may be a bug). So, https://script.google.com/macros/u/1/s/AKfycbwYbJ5WvIRmizYMr8MMtNVdIodpdYcJHz4DuO97Oxnuw4lnu3k/exec becomes https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwYbJ5WvIRmizYMr8MMtNVdIodpdYcJHz4DuO97Oxnuw4lnu3k/exec
- You need to add a trigger to your script. When you hit the url, that trigger will call a particular function of your script. **What you need to do is set a trigger that fires doPost() whenever submit is clicked**. doPost() sends your email.

**Notes:**

1. How to add trigger? Go to Edit > Current projects' trigger (or we can use the clock button too). Add your trigger there. Under run, select doPost(), under event select from spreadsheet -> then on form submit. Save it.
2. When you access https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwYbJ5WvIRmizYMr8MMtNVdIodpdYcJHz4DuO97Oxnuw4lnu3k/exec from browser (without /u/1 :-) ) it will give error that doGet() function is not present which is true and your web browser sent a GET request.

Comment: Now its working but I am not getting the data inside the data key of the json object. Its completely empty.

Comment: You need to give name attributes to your input and textarea element. Eg: <input name="blah"...  Also accept my solution as the answer if you think so. =D